# Callback when Fragment is active/visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

Is there a callback so I can know when a user goes from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB` ?

I would like to catch this behaviour in FragmentB so I can perform some actions...

Comment: have you got it working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The below is the callback when a fragment is visible to user.**

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) { 
            DO YOUR OPERATIONS HERE
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't seem to get invoked on 5.0.1

Comment: Does not seem to be a reliable method. I have tried this with tab layout, android is highly inconsistent in calls to `setUserVisibleHint` method.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
supportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
    override fun onFragmentStarted(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
        // your logic here
    }
}, false)
```

You may want to set the last parameter to true in case you also want to be alerted of fragments started in child fragment managers.

Answer (score -3):

you can check by using onPause and onResume states of the fragments.

if you want to check whether FragmentB come to front then simply print a toast message in onResume in the FragmentB.

Comment: fragments `onPause` and `onResume` are closely associated with corresponding activities events. They dont work the way you are thinking. They will get fired on fragment when the activities corresponding  events will get fired.